# BigInteger logic problems in simple statement

Tags: java, biginteger, logical-operators

So I'm writing a primality test program, and somewhere along my code I have this:

```
BigInteger temp = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
BigInteger p_Big = BigInteger.valueOf(p); // p is just an integer

temp = power(a, p-1); // a method to calculate a^(p-1)
temp = temp.mod(p_Big);

if(temp != BigInteger.ONE){
    return false;
}
```

Problem is, I get `false` for values that should've returned `true`, and the weird thing is that when I do

```
System.out.println(temp+","+BigInteger.ONE);
```

for `p = 5, a = 2` I get

```
1,1
```

So what's causing it to return `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
if(temp != BigInteger.ONE)
```

with

```
if(!temp.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
```